# jqgrid advanced search input has no attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I use both advanced search and filterToolbar. Both share most searchOptions.
I set the searchoptions.dataInit dynamically, and need the attr "name" of the element, in order to get some colmodel attrs for the current col, like this...

```
searchoptions.dataInit = function(element) {
   console.log(element);
   var colName = $(element).attr('name'));
   var attrs = $grid.jqGrid('getColProp', colName);
   (hwere set some different datePicker options depending on col attrs ...)
}
```

This works fine in filterToolbar situation, but not in advanced search.
IN dataInit I debug "element" ...

- When in "filterToolbar" it prints ...
  input type="text" name="prc_start" id="gs_prc_start" value class="hasDatepicker"
- When in "Search form" it prints ... input type="text" id="jqg2" role="textbox" class="input-elm hasDatepicker">

So, in the second situation I can't get the field name, which I need to get some colmodel params.

How can I solve this? 
(jqGrid v4.6.0, I can't upgrade version by now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, which you describe exist only in old jqGrid 4.6. As the workaround I could recommend you to use the follow

```
searchoptions.dataInit = function(element) {
    var $td = $(element).closest("td.data");
    if ($td.length > 0) {
        // in searching dialog
        alert($td.siblings(".columns").find("select").val());
    }
    ...
}
```

The `$td` (`var $td = $(element).closest("td.data");`) will be the outer cell, which contains the input with the datepicker. `$td.siblings(".columns")` will the the cell with the name on the column and `$td.siblings(".columns").find("select").val()` get you the column name.

Comment: Oleg: excelent, it works! Thank you! (sorry I still cannot vote)

Comment: I didn't tried "closest("td.data")" before, since I read other responses where you said that dataInit element is created before appended to real dom, so I guessed it would not work ...closest("td.data");